# Value of ASP:Textbox set by Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have seen a couple of other questions similar to this, mine seems to have a weird twist. I've got a timesheet web app, an employee submits their time in a table, it gets sent to H.R. as readonly. H.R. can then approve or reject their timesheet depending on certain criteria. I thought it would be nice if the H.R. Rep could click on cells that were incorrect and turn them red, thus when it's rejected and sent back to the employee it'd be easy to see what they need to correct.

I wrote this little snippet in Javascript which works well:

```js
    var validTextArray = {};
    var backgroundColorArray = {};
    function clearTextBox(textBoxID) 
    {
        if (document.getElementById(textBoxID).value != "#ERROR")
        {
            backgroundColorArray[textBoxID] = document.getElementById(textBoxID).style.backgroundColor;
            validTextArray[textBoxID] = document.getElementById(textBoxID).value;
            document.getElementById(textBoxID).value = "#ERROR";
            document.getElementById(textBoxID).style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }
        else if (validTextArray[textBoxID] != null)
        {
            document.getElementById(textBoxID).value = validTextArray[textBoxID];
            document.getElementById(textBoxID).style.backgroundColor = backgroundColorArray[textBoxID];
        }
    }
```

and to be clear about my c# here's that:

```js
            day1PH.Attributes["onclick"] = "clearTextBox(this.id)";
            day1PN.Attributes["onclick"] = "clearTextBox(this.id)";
            day1LV.Attributes["onclick"] = "clearTextBox(this.id)";
            day1TL.Attributes["onclick"] = "clearTextBox(this.id)";

            day2PH.Attributes["onclick"] = "clearTextBox(this.id)";
            day2PN.Attributes["onclick"] = "clearTextBox(this.id)";
            day2LV.Attributes["onclick"] = "clearTextBox(this.id)";
//etc...
```

This part works beautifully, the issue is that I need to be able to capture those errors. Now when H.R. hits the reject button all the data in the table is rewritten to an SQL Database, but because the text was set by javascript the "#ERROR" values don't come through.

What can I do to capture those values?

Comment: I think you are accidentally clearing the textboxes before they get to the database.   When you use JavaScript to set the text of an Asp:TextBox, the text is there when you do a postback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are using webforms, if you are, you can use a hidden field and set the value property with the error, then when you post the form to your webserver you can grab this value by using Request.Form["nameOfYourHiddenAttribute"].

```
<input id="hdnErrors" type="hidden" name="error" value="xpto">

string error = Request.Form["error"] + ""; //error is 'xpto'
```

if you have multiple errors, you can use some dictionary in javascript and in the end you can serialize to json object e put it in the hidden value and then, in your server side code, you can deserialize and use it.

Something like this (didn't test it)

```
var arrayObject = [];
var error = {txtId = "txt1", description="HR error"};
arrayObject.push(error);

document.getElementById('hdnErrors').value = JSON.stringify(arrayObject);
```

Comment: This does work, can you possibly elaborate why I need to use a hidden field instead of say, naming my existing asp:textboxs and using your Request.Form[] method?

Comment: In WebForms all the information that are rendered to the browser in serverControls are saved in a special hidden field generated by the platform called ViewState. Since this is the way webforms "simulate" a connection in a stateless http world, all information are on way-only, server-to-client, anything extra with client code only takes effect in the client because you are not applying this in the viewState (if you do, the server validates the view state and if it's different from the original you will get an error of "invalid viewState").